# Html Tab icon not showing on IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, favicon

I'm trying to set a custom icon for a html on IE, with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hotel</title>
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico"  type="image/x-icon">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The files are also in the correct folders and the name are also correct. And I've also set the rel to shortcut icon, but the icon won't show on IE. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

With Internet Explorer you'll need to use a *real .ico* file (not a renamed one) - you can use [this site](https://www.favicon-generator.org/) to generate one.

You'll also need to specify `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />` in the `head` tag to make it appear in Internet Explorer.

Finally, ensure you're hosting the webpage on a server (`http://` prefix), since Internet Explorer won't render favicons correctly when running files from the file system (`file:///` prefix)

Comment: yes, that is the real .ico file and I've also generated it there. But it didn't work on IE but it worked on other browser.

Comment: Hi, have you tried adding the `"shortcut icon"` link ? Also, please make sure the path to the icon is correct (you can use `/favicon.ico` if it's in the project's root directory), and clear the browser cache.

Comment: Yes, I've also tried putting in shortcut icon and also used "/favicon.ico". But it didn't work. Maybe you can send me a sample of yours?

Comment: Oh wait... are you opening the `.html` file on a server (`http(s)://` prefix) or from your file system (`file:///` prefix) ? Internet Explorer won't render favicons correctly when running files from the file system

Comment: Ah yes, I'm testing this on the file system. So what should I do?

Comment: You can create a server to serve local files: if you have Node.js you can use [express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) or even deploy it on heroku - see [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/wh1tney/2ad13aa5fbdd83f6a489) to deploy a static folder (not tested)

Comment: _Edit:_ I just tested the tutorial method, deploying it via heroku works with IE 11.

Comment: right, I just hosted a server and it worked! turns out It only works on a server in IE! not with a file system!

Comment: I've edited my answer, glad to see it works ;)